# Netflix over mhl (usbC to hdmi aadapter) what could cause fail?

Tags: hdmi, mhl, netflix, usb-c, samsung-dex

I am wondering why when I start Netflix's app it fails to playback any video (even downloaded ones).
Youtube works just fine, it's only an app running on Desktop looking environment.

So is it the DRM that could forbid that without an app knowing, I am not trying to ask an app specific thing, but globally for any app if DRM framework is the cause. Like for instance when a banking app blurs out, it's not the app causing it, but the category of the app.

The full setup looks like this:

- 1 Samsung S10
- A smart tv (MHL compatible)
- 1 cheap usb-C to HDMI adapter
- A long HDMI cable
  (which doesn't matter at this point, since we have a connection to the tv)
- A Samsung Dex running
- Target app is in maximized window

(Please don't flag the question if it's poorly written, I really think this is a problem that some people will find it useful if solved, especially if they want to watch videos using some evil DRM based apps)

Comment: What happens when you try to stream the Netflix app to the TV without Samsung Dex?

Comment: I don''t think that a banking app is comparable with a streaming app. Banking apps usually set the `SECURE` flag on each activity which prevents the activity from being displayed in the recents list (and may be also via MHL?).

Comment: When I use normal HDMI mirror mode it doesn't care, but when in Dex mode, probably sets environment variables that it is streaming on HDMI or second screen, I need to capture the env changes in adb shell somehow to prove the theory. I am open to any advices on how to monitor variables or if possible to use strace (without root) :).